# How to send private message to user before accept join channel request with python telegram bot?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

When subscribing to certain channels, administrator approval is required. These channels use hidden links and do not have any usernames. After requesting to join, I am being asked questions by a bot  to verify if I am a real user. I have been encountering this frequently lately. How can I achieve this using python-telegram-bot? Just explaining the logic would be sufficient. I am familiar with coding. Any hints would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If your bot has the required permissions in the chat in question, it will receive [`chat_join_request`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.update.html#telegram.Update.chat_join_request) updates when a user requests to join. In PTB you can catch those with the [`ChatJoinRequestHandler`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.chatjoinrequesthandler.html#chatjoinrequesthandler). Your bot can then send (a single!) message to the user and if the user replies, it can also send more messages. Finally, your bot can [approve](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.approve_chat_join_request) or [reject](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.decline_chat_join_request) the request.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telelegram-bot`.

Answer (score 2):

As @callmestag explained above. Here is the piece of code(in pyTelegramBotApi library)

```
@bot.chat_join_request_handler()
def handle_join_request(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    bot.send_message(user_id "message text")
    bot.approve_chat_join_request(message.chat.id, user_id)
    print(f"Request Approved for {user_id}")
```